# APK not found issue

Tags: android, apk, mips

I am new to android development, I apologize that similar questions has been asked already but nothing works for me.

I have successfully build hello-jni for MIPS and it works perfectly on MIPS emulator but I am unable to find apk file so that I can install it my device. I am using eclipse helios. JDK 1.6 on windows 7 64bit.

Please help!

Comment: look at your bin folder in your project. there should be placed a debug apk of your application.

Comment: please add all the things that didn't work.

Comment: Just try to clean your project and Re-Build it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in Android application when you build a application then the generated .apk file is created in `<Application_Name>/bin` directory..